# Rhythmbox and external hard drive

Tags: rhythmbox

I keep my whole music collection on my external hard drive. Is it better to import those files into Rhythmbox library or should I make my hard drive recognized as mp3 player by putting .as_music_player in it's root?

Comment: If I mark my external hard drive as mp3 player rhythmbox reimports the whole folders again when I reconnect the drive, but if I manually import the library it just rescans it. So, I think importing the music collection from external hard drive is a better soulution than marking the drive as mp3 player.

Answer (score 0):

In Rhythmbox, click Edit->Preferences->Music Tab, and point the Library Location to the music library on your external hdd.

Comment: That's not what he asked.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. I asked whats better.

Comment: I think that as long as a method does what you want, it is the best for you, and if there are several ways to achieve the same goal, then generally they are equal, unless the user decides that some are better.